# document.frame is not working in ie11

Tags: javascript

I am getting undefined object error while executing in ie 11 without compatible mode. it works fine in ie 11 compatible mode.

Sample code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script>
        function test() {
            var parent = document.getElementById("tabPaneMain");
            var doc = document;
            var html = '<div class="tab-page" id="tabCust" style="width: 100%; height: 95%">'
                    + '<h2 class="tab">Customer</h2>'
                    + '<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width="100%" height="100%">'
                    + '<tr><td valign=top id=iframeparent_tabCust>'
                    + '<iframe name="iframe_tabCust" id="iframe_tabCust" src="overview.html" style="width=100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder=0></iframe>'
                    + '</td></tr></table></div>';

            var node = doc.createElement("DIV");
            node.innerHTML = html;
            parent.appendChild(node);
            var test = node.document.frames["iframe_tabCust"];// undefined error: when execute in ie 11 without compatibile mode

        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabPaneMain" style="left: 10px; height: 100%" />
    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="test();">
        click
    </button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the code formatting in the future and not a quote block. I edited it so it shows up correctly.

Comment: Would it work if you’d remove the `document.`? That is `var test = node.frames["iframe_tabCust"];`.

Comment: no its not working. it return unable to get property.

Answer (score 1):

Your `node` variable is a `div` element.   Last I checked, a div doesn't have a `document` property. so `node.document` will be undefined and thus `node.document.frames` will be an error.

`window.frames` is the standard place where you get a list of frames.

---

Since you have a unique id on your frame, probably the simplest and "cross browser supported" way to obtain the frame is:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_tabCust")
```

Comment: @pranav - Already tried what?  You're inserting an element with `id="iframe_tabCust"`.  Unless you goofed with the HTML or a typo somewhere, you should be able to find that element with `document.getElementById("iframe_tabCust")` just fine.  I'd suggest you troubleshoot why that isn't working because it's the obvious way to code this.  Supply us a jsFiddle demo and we'll debug it for you.

Comment: @pranav - FYI, `document.getElementById("iframe_tabCust")` works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4eob4gar/ so there must be something else going on in your real code that you have not disclosed.  Also, why do you take 13 hours to respond to answers.  This site doesn't work very well if you're gone that long.

Comment: i had tried "
document.getElementById("iframe_tabCust")" its working fine in sample code but dont why its not working in actual code. any doc type issue or what i dont know exactly.. please help me on that. and thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well a node should not have a document so it should be

```
window.frames["iframe_tabCust"]
```

or just reference it by id

```
document.getElementById("iframe_tabCust")
```